# Wordpress - How to load content from phpfile into custom admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I found this script online which adds a menu item and a page with content from a php function.

However i cant seem to get the content to load from the admin-handleiding.php file.

.

wp-content/theme/functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'Website handleiding', 'Handleiding', 'manage_options', 'admin-handleiding.php', 'handleiding_admin_page', 'dashicons-media-document', 6    );
}

function handleiding_admin_page(){
?>
<div class="wrap">
        <h2>Website handleiding</h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, im awake for too long. Forgot to include/require the page ^^